# Ruby Undefined method downcase

Tags: ruby, exception, gsub

I'm getting an exception in the following piece of code. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how I can prevent it?

```
def self.find_by_data(data = {})
            where(name_canonical: data['name'].downcase.gsub(/\s+/, ''),
                  fuel:           data['fuel'],
                  trim_canonical: data['trim'].downcase.gsub(/\s+/, ''),
                  year:           data['year']).first
        end
```

Exception:

```
/Users/charlie/Documents/WIP/projectx/ar_models.rb:35:in `find_by_data': undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)ooooooooooooooooooooooooo| ETA:   0:00:00
    from /Users/charlie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:36:in `block in find_by_data'
    from /Users/charlie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:845:in `block in scoping'
    from /Users/charlie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:270:in `scoping'
    from /Users/charlie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:845:in `scoping'
    from /Users/charlie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:36:in `find_by_data'
    from /Users/charlie/Documents/WIP/projectx/ar_models.rb:132:in `create_or_assign_existing'
    from /Users/charlie/Documents/WIP/projectx/app.rb:230:in `block (2 levels) in work'
    from /Users/charlie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
    from /Users/charlie/Documents/WIP/projectx/app.rb:80:in `block in work'
    from /Users/charlie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/parallel-0.6.3/lib/parallel.rb:319:in `call'
    from /Users/charlie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/parallel-0.6.3/lib/parallel.rb:319:in `call_with_index'
    from /Users/charlie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/parallel-0.6.3/lib/parallel.rb:179:in `block (3 levels) in work_in_threads'
    from /Users/charlie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/parallel-0.6.3/lib/parallel.rb:326:in `with_instrumentation'
    from /Users/charlie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/parallel-0.6.3/lib/parallel.rb:177:in `block (2 levels) in work_in_threads'
    from /Users/charlie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/parallel-0.6.3/lib/parallel.rb:171:in `loop'
    from /Users/charlie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/parallel-0.6.3/lib/parallel.rb:171:in `block in work_in_threads'
    from /Users/charlie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/parallel-0.6.3/lib/parallel.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in in_threads'
```

Comment: we don't know what your hash `data` contain.. But it is very clear that either `data['name']` or `data['trim']` contains `nil`. Check the  same

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you see "undefined method `...` for nil:NilClass" it means you have a `nil` value you're trying to call the method on.

In this case, something like `data['name']` is not defined.

To make this more bullet-proof:

```
data['name'].to_s.downcase.gsub(/\s+/, '')
```

This converts everything to string to start with. `nil.to_s` is an empty string by default, so it's safe.

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary oprators perhaps:

```
def self.find_by_data(data = {})
            where(name_canonical: data['name'] == nil ? '' : data['name'].downcase.gsub(/\s+/, ''),
                  fuel:           data['fuel'],
                  trim_canonical: data['trim'] == nil ? '' : data['name'].downcase.gsub(/\s+/, ''),
                  year:           data['year']).first
        end
```

Comment: `== nil` is supremely ugly. A better alternative is `.nil?` but only if that value might be `false`. Even better in this case is: `data['name'] ? data['name'].downcase.gsub(...) : ''`

Comment: @tadman Yet it's a solution. A better one please? Do we have to go after `has_key?`? But wouldn't `nil` still be possible for that and that we have to check again?

Comment: I've posted my own take that involves `to_s` which forces the value to a string, regardless of if it's `nil` or not. 99% of the time `x == nil` can be replaced with `!x` or in this case, simply reversing the ternary.

Comment: Now that's ugly for me.

Comment: It's the same thing you have, minus `== nil`, reversing the logic.

Comment: As you said, not having nil could still apply to `false`. Also a `to_s` method is a dirty hack.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
data['name']
```

or

```
data['trim']
```

is a nil.
Check your input data.